# ngrx: loading state for each element in collection

Tags: angular, ngrx, state-management

I have a state for the page with the list of items. Each item has it's own loading state depending on the few actions, that can be made in it.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to update loading state for the item:

- expand the model for the item with `loading` property;
- add `loadingIds` property to the state object and add/remove the ids from it. In this case, is it fine to use `Set`? Should this `Set` be immutable and recreated every time? Or just use `add`/`delete` methods in it?

Maybe there're another good options for that? I don't really like any of the ways I've described above..

Comment: How did you resolve it finally? I am facing similar problem.

Comment: @Mateusz, I just continued to use separate property loadingIds as it's described in my question

Answer (score 2):

Items are items, loading state is a loading state. You can mix them, but a better way is to keep things simple.

I would recommend simply to implement `loadingIds` and selectors that allow to fetch current loading state.

Instead of the `Set` use an array of ids.

To add loading

```
state.loadingIds = [...state.loadingIds, id];
```

To check loading

```
state.loadingIds.indexOf(id) !== -1;
```

To remove loading

```
state.loadingIds = state.loadingIds.filter(loadingId => loadingId !== id);
```

Comment: I have a question regarding this approach.

Using `isLoading` property makes it easy to use  with `*ngFor="let item of (items$ | async)"` and then just indicate  using `item.isLoading` inside the loop.

 Is there any way to handle it easily in html later on using your approach and selectors ? I cant imagine mixing ids with loadingIds and then filtering.

Comment: @Mateusz in your component you may expand item interface with loading property, just combine 2 state selectors like `combineLatest(state.items$, state.loadingIds$).pipe(map(([items, ids]) => items.map(item => ({...item, loading: ids.has(item.id) } )))`

Comment: Also, using arrays to store IDs is not a good idea, because each time you will loop through them, consider using set or object instead

Comment: mixing item interface with isLoading conflicts with SOLID approach. If you have a lot of items and each item is loading separately, you can create a pipe which checks the loading status for each item: `<div *ngIf="item | isLoading | async">loading</div>`, and the pipe is checking `indexOf` in current status.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the ngrx-loading-state lib:

https://github.com/amzhang/ngrx-loading-state

Demo for what you are looking for is here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rocjzb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

(go to the "Id Loading State Demo" tab)

It's boilerplatey, but such is life using NgRx.